# Dealing with ties in quantcut()

Tags: r, grouping, quantile

I'm trying to use the R function quantcut() to recode a numeric variable as a factor with levels corresponding to quantiles. For example:

```
> X
[1]  6  4  9  6  1  2  5  3  5  7 10  7  2  7  7  5  6  6  3  4  6  4  2  7  6  7
[27]  4  3  5  3  7  6  8 12  4  4  0  1  7  6  7  4  7  1  1  1  2  3  3  1  1  6
[53]  5  3  1  1  1  3  3  3  1  1  3  1  1  1  3  3  0  1  3  1  8  5  3  0  0  2
[79]  1  3  8  0  1  4  1  1  1  1  1  1  3  2  1  4  1  5  5 12  7  2  6  6  2  6
[105]  0  1  4  1  4  0  7  3  2  1  1  8  5  5  3  0  5  6  2  4  2  2  2  6  4  2
[131]  2  2  2  6  8  5  1  2  8  3  2  7  4  6  6  6  7  5  1  5  5  6  1  4  4  5
[157]  6  2  4  7  2  4 10  6  3  5  2  2  6  6  2  4  5  7  4  5 11  6  6  8  2  4
[183]  4  6 12 16  9  7 14 13 11  5  5  2  2  7  7  6  4  3  4  3  5  4  5  7  9  4
[209]  3 12  4  4  4  8  7  6  1  3  6  7  5  5  6  9  6  4  7  8  5  6  3  6  4  7
[235]  3  3  4  7  5  7  5  9  5  8  3  4  3  2  5  2  4  3  8  4  2  2  1  5  3  5
[261]  8  5  6  4  5  1  1  2  6  2  7  2  4  4  3  3  4 10  5  6 10  2  5  5  0  1
[287]  6  2  5  4  6  6  9  5  5  6  3  8  1  5  1  8  5  2  5  2  4  2  4  4

bins=10
labels = 1:bins
library(gtools)
x2 = quantcut(X, q = seq(0, 1, by=1/bins), labels=labels)
```

I get the error: "Error in cut.default(x[!flag], breaks = newquant, include.lowest = TRUE,  : 
  'breaks' are not unique". I thought this was because there are ties in the quantiles, but the documentation for quantcut specifically shows an example of how the function can handle ties by using fewer intervals. The error occurs regardless of whether I specify the labels argument.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is code to enter the variable X:

```
X = c(6L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
6L, 8L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
0L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 
7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
2L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 16L, 9L, 
7L, 14L, 13L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 
3L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
7L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 
10L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the issue can be traced to here, where as you say, the 70% and 80% quantiles are the same. `quantile` is used internally by `quantcut`

```
quantile(X,probs=seq(0,1,0.1))
  0%  10%  20%  30%  40%  50%  60%  70%  80%  90% 100% 
 0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.6  4.0  5.0  6.0  6.0  8.0 16.0
```

I can't see how to address this issue using `quantcut` itself, but you could always just use `cut` and `quantile` and `unique` in combination to sort it out. From what I can tell, this is what `quantcut` does internally when there are ties anyway.

```
result <- cut(X,unique(quantile(X,probs=seq(0,1,0.1))),include.lowest=TRUE)

> result[2:10]
 [1] (3.6,4] (8,16]  (5,6]   [0,1]   (1,2]   (4,5]   (2,3]   (4,5]   (6,8]  
#Levels: [0,1] (1,2] (2,3] (3,3.6] (3.6,4] (4,5] (5,6] (6,8] (8,16]
> X[2:10]
 [1]      4      9      6       1       2       5       3       5       7
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been playing with this, and I don't understand why it is level 4 that gets omitted rather than level 8 or 9 (since those levels represent the tied quantiles). If I call levels(result), it lists 1:9. But if I call table(result), there are 0 observations of level 4.

Comment: @half-pass - I'm guessing this is because the quantile grouping is `>3 to 3.6` in which it is impossible for an integer to fall into. You might need to `floor` the break points of the `cut` function to get some values to fall into that grouping: `result <- cut(X,unique(floor(quantile(X,probs=seq(0,1,0.1)))),include.lowest=TRUE)`

Comment: Is it possible to use this solution and still keep quantile labels? I've tried your suggestion including labels like this: `result <- cut(X, labels=c(1:10), breaks= unique(quantile(X,probs=seq(0,1,0.1))),include.lowest=TRUE)`   but I get an Error: `lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ`